Proper OAuth 2.0 authentication flow for a Power App - Power Automate - Azure APIM - Backend Service
There is a scenario where users login to a Power App using their Office 365 credentials. The Power App invokes a Power Automate flow. There is a need for the Power Automate flow to invoke a backend service through Azure API Management. Microsoft Entra is being used as the Identity Provider.
The best way in my opinion is to go through the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow, through which the Power Automate can issue an access token containing the logged in User ID as a claim, it can then invoke APIM, APIM can validate the access token, and the backend service can get the user information using the User ID so as to further receive the user profile.
As far as I know, that flow works in pair with the OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow, which can't be used in this case, as it requires the user to log in to a browser window and also the user has logged in with their Office 365 creds already.
That being said the correct flow seems to be what is described here. (Get access on behalf of a user). But I am not able to try this, because I cannot invoke the /authorize endpoint to get the Auth Code (this opens a browser window for the user to interact).
Instead I have tried what is descibed here. (Get access without a user)
Do you know if there is a straightforward way to achive this?

share the steps you have tried so far

@IkhtesamAfrin Please check again. I have edited the original question.
